# excel: multiple conditions - IF repeat value

Tags: excel, nested, excel-2010

My first question on stackoverflow - I apologise for any lack of clarity in writing this up.

I am using MS Excel 2010 on Windows 7 Professional.

---

Each cell in column G needs to be populated

with values from the corresponding cell in column Q (number)

IF

1) values in column F (unix timestamp) are repeat values

AND

2) FOR EACH REPEAT VALUE RANGE, values in column D (string) include BOTH "spanish" AND "global".

THEN

3) ONLY FOR THE ROWS MENTIONING "global" in column D, should the values from column Q be populated in the corresponding cell in column G.

---

EXAMPLE:

Take rows 21 to 23 in the attached screenshot [edit: no screenshot possible, I need at least 10 reputation, bummer]. The values in column F (unix timestamp conversion) are identical for cells F21 to F23 (25569.52232). In addition, for this range both "spanish" (D23) and "global" (D21) appear in column D. Therefore, cell G21 should be populated with the value of cell Q21.

---

BACKGROUND:

I am trying to find a formula which will allow me to investigate what the impact of facebook same-day posting is - i.e. if I post once in "spanish" and once "global(ly)" on the same day, I want to have a way to look at the reach of those global posts separately. I will not bore you with further details.

---

DUMMY DATA

```
    D          E                 F                    G                     Q
1   post       unix timestamp    unix ts conversion   sameday post reach    total reach 
2              1379538602        25569.5224                                 817
3   spanish    1379510856        25569.5224                                 8184
4              1379508149        25569.5224                                 15480
5              1379452202        25569.52239                                3190
6   spanish    1379430258        25569.52239                                14656
7              1379428201        25569.52239                                24328
8   global     1379418873        25569.52239           <???>                140800
9   ...        ...               ...                                        ...
```

Comment: It is hard to understand without sample data, but I am guessing it is a combination of functions: `IF(AND())`

Comment: @zx8754 I would be more than happy to provide you with sample data but, unfortunately, I do not have enough "reputation" to upload my spreadsheet. The reason I find this so tricky is the condition concerning the repeat unix timestamp values in column F. A simple IF(AND()) combination will not do the trick here. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: only 4-5 columns mentioned in your question, please make a toy example and paste it as normal text.

Comment: If you decide to downvote this question, please take a moment to comment and explain how it could be improved, I will do my best to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

Put this formula in `G1` and pull it down.

`=IF(AND(COUNTIF(F:F,F1)>1,D1="global"),Q1,"")`

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Explanation**

1. `COUNTIF(F:F,F1)>1` This checks for repeat values. i.e if there is more than one occurrence in col `F`
2. `D1="global"` This check if the value in the respective cell in Col `D` had "Global"
3. `And()` is used so that we can check if both the above conditions satisfy.
4. `If` is used so that if the conditions satisfy then show the value in `G` from respective cell in `Q`

Comment: thank you for taking the time to post. this is pointing me in the right direction, but did not quite do the job. what i get with this formula are empty cells throughout. i have edited my question above and entered dummy data. again, i would be very grateful for suggestions, thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: @tkamb checked this solution on your dummy data, it works.

Comment: @zx8754 thank you, i think i know where the problem is now. the unix timestamp in column E (and the derived unix ts conversion in column F) are derived from another column in my spreadsheet (column P) which is a date-time format. so for P2 it is 2013-09-18  16:10:02 -- the underlying formula in column F is =(I2/86400)+25569+(1/24). i probably should have mentioned this before, it just did not occur to me, apologies. is it possible that this is the reason why the formula returns only blank cells when i apply it to my spreadsheet? if so, how can i cirumvent the problem?

Comment: What is the value of `I2`? And why do we need to do conversion?

Comment: @zx8754 sorry wrong copy paste: the underlying formula in column F is =(P2/86400)+25569+(1/24) -- where value in column P2 is 2013-09-18 16:10:02 

-- the reason why i am converting the unix timestamp in column F is that i need a unique value for each yyyymmdd

-- the "pure" unix timestamp in column E is not unique for each day

let me know if further clarification is required.

Comment: `=DAY(A1)&"/"&MONTH(A1)&"/"&YEAR(A1)` Use this to convert to date without hours.

Comment: Seems like I missed the party :) Just saw the dummy data. what happens if set col F to show 6 decimal places. Are the first 3 rows in Col F still equal?

Comment: @zx8754 thank you, i used the formula you gave me to convert the unix timestamp to date without hours, however i get a #NUM! error for all the cells. checked the cell formatting options, set it to general, number, custom (yyymmdd) but still to no success. any idea what i'm doing wrong?